# Google Billing V3 Crashing after using it again

Tags: android, payment, billing, beta

I have created a simple app that includes  Google billing v3. It just has a simple button which you click on it and the payment is done. So far the app is uploaded as a Beta Version and works. But when you launching it and click the payment botton it crashes. Here is the exception I get from the crash report of the google play developer console.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at victory.walkto.testingpaymentsb.MainActivity$2.
onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4502)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18857)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5420)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:857)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:673)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I really don't understant that. Why do I get a null pointer exception? The code  is the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

IInAppBillingService mService;
ServiceConnection connection;
String inappid = "victory.walkto.testingpaymentsb.productid"; //replace this with your in-app product id
Button purchaseBtn;
Button clickBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");

    // first this
    connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    // then this
    bindService(serviceIntent,connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    purchaseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purchase);
    clickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    clickBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
            skuList.add(inappid);
            Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
            querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
            Bundle skuDetails;
            try {
                skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                        "inapp", querySkus);

                int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (response == 0) {

                    ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
                            .getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                    for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                        String sku = object.getString("productId");
                        String price = object.getString("price");
                        if (sku.equals(inappid)) {
                            System.out.println("price " + price);
                            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService
                                    .getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku,
                                            "inapp",
                                            "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                                    .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                            startIntentSenderForResult(
                                    pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                                    new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                    Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                            purchaseBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            clickBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I am clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString(inappid);
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "You have bought the " + sku
                                + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (connection != null) {
        unbindService(connection);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what's line 92 of MainActivity ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Comment: Fixed. By default Google doesn't allow you to buy the item twice. It has to do with tokens. I order to fixed I had to use a method mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), purchaseToken); In other words,I had to purchase the item first.